# Latex Environment with named optional parameters

Tags: xparse, optional-arguments

Is there a way to get a string options in `\NewDocumentEnvironment`or `\newenvironment` ?

i.e

```
\begin{foo}[color=red,size=12pt]

\end{foo}
```

where the environment is defined as

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{}
{
...start something
}
{
...end something
}
```

This is a simplified version of what I actually need, but instead of being too specific and getting complicated, I simplified the problem to make it easier to follow.

Comment: well do `\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{O{}}` and then use some keyval-system to process the argument.

Comment: ok, I wasn't sure if that was how to do it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use most (any?) of the known key=value interfaces, for instance the following uses `expkv` (with the key-defining frontend provided by `expkv-def`) to set up your keys. (*Disclaimer*: I'm `expkv`'s author)

Other notable packages that you could use for this are:

- `keyval` (very basic, but faster than any other solution, there is a bug regarding stripping braces but that's a non-issue most of the time)
- `l3keys` (part of the `expl3` programming interface)
- `\DeclareKeys`/`\SetKeys` (part of the LaTeX kernel, another interface to `l3keys`)
- `pgfkeys` (similar bug to `keyval`, but rich feature set)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-def}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\ekvdefinekeys{foo}
  {
     store  color = \foo@color
    ,edimen size  = \foo@size
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{O{}}
  {%
    \ekvset{foo}{#1}%
    start something
    \color{\foo@color}%
    \fontsize{\foo@size}{\fpeval{1.2*\foo@size}pt}\selectfont
  }
  {%
    end something
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{foo}[color=red,size=12pt]
  Some contents.
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you don't need any of the key-values in the end part (or use two different key-macros, one in the `\begin` and one in the `\end` part, if you're fine with parsing twice) of your environment you could also use `expkv-cs`, with which it is pretty straight forward to define small macros having few keys (but be warned, it doesn't scale as nicely as other key=value interfaces, it's main advantage is being fully expandable, which is absolutely unnecessary for use in an environment...).

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
% \ekvcSplit sets up a macro using up to nine different keys as ordinary
% arguments in the replacement text. Comments after the keys just to keep track
% of the argument numbers, not necessary for its syntax.
\ekvcSplit\fookeys
  {
     color = black % #1
    ,size  = \f@size % #2
  }
  {%
    \color{#1}%
    \fontsize{#2}{\fpeval{1.2*#2}pt}\selectfont
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{O{}}
  {%
    start something
    \fookeys{#1}%
  }
  {%
    end something
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{foo}[color=red,size=12pt]
  Some contents.
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

Output like above.

Comment: you mis-spelled `feature`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just to give you a reason to interact with me :*